# how to install mongo-org-tools in centos docker container using dockerfile?

Tags: mongodb, docker, centos, dockerfile, docker-image

I want to have mongo-org-tools installed in my container because I want to use the tools like mongorestore and mongodump inside my container.

As the documentation of mongodb suggests, to add a repo file in conf folder which is required in CentOS. I tried doing this  with dockerfile but it didn't get executed.

Is there any way of doing this via dockerfile or am i doing something wrong?

**Dockerfile**:

```
FROM centos

# Create app directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# RUN adduser -G root node

#ENV http_proxy http://172.26.25.4:8080/
#ENV https_proxy http://172.26.25.4:8080/

# Install app dependencies
# A wildcard is used to ensure both package.json AND package-lock.json are copied
# where available (npm@5+)
COPY package*.json ./
COPY SmallTalkWorkspace*.json ./
COPY bin ./bin
COPY helpers ./helpers
COPY src ./src

ADD ./mongodb-org-4.0.repo /etc/yum.repos.d/

 RUN yum -y update && \
     yum -y install epel-release && \
     yum -y install nodejs npm && \
     yum -y install mongodb-org-shell mongodb-org-tools && \
     yum clean all && \
     mkdir -p /var/lib/mongo && \
     chown -R mongod:mongod /var/lib/mongo

VOLUME ["/var/lib/mongo"]

RUN ["/usr/bin/mongod", "--dbpath", "/var/lib/mongo"]

EXPOSE 5000
# USER node

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

**mongodb-org-4.0.repo**

```
[mongodb-org-4.0]
name=MongoDB Repository
baseurl=https://repo.mongodb.org/yum/redhat/$releasever/mongodb-org/4.0/x86_64/
gpgcheck=1
enabled=1
gpgkey=https://www.mongodb.org/static/pgp/server-4.0.asc
```

Comment: yes it's very common to do it via Dockerfile. Can you post your Dockerfile to see why might be the problem?

Comment: @pacuna I have added the dockerfile and the mongo repo file both of which are present in my root directory. Can you please tell me what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Take a look at this [link](https://github.com/CentOS/CentOS-Dockerfiles/blob/master/mongodb/centos7/Dockerfile).

Answer (score 0):

You need to also install the mongodb-org package to create the user.

Comment: i had tried with that as well, it crashed. Is this the correct implementation?

Comment: I ran your same dockerfile but also adding that package and it all went well. Before that I had a mongod user error. Although of course I didn't test your node app which might be causing the crash.

Comment: but if you see, i want mongo and my node app both running, but when "RUN ["/usr/bin/mongod", "--dbpath", "/var/lib/mongo"]" command is executed, it doesn't move ahead. I want the app i am running at port 5000 also to be running.

Comment: oh I see what you're saying. That's why normally you want to use something like docker compose to have separate containers for the different processes. The best solution would be to run mongo in its own container and your app in another. Then your containers can communicate each other via service name.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do something like this:

```
FROM centos:7.6.1810

WORKDIR /usr/src

RUN curl -sL **rpm nodesource url** | bash - && \
    yum install wget -y && \
    wget **rpm URL** && \
    yum localinstall mongodb-org-tools-4.0.15-1.el7.x86_64.rpm -y
```